# Applying for Open Graph Action which includes User Messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying to get "Comment" action approved from Facebook, The action requires users to submit a message when they click on the Comment button.

The link can be found here http://sample.fandrop.com/timeline/comments.html

Here's what I have provided as steps to reproduce the action when User Messages checkbox is checked

```
Step 1- Visit http://sample.fandrop.com/timeline/comments.html
Step 2- Login using your facebook account
Step 3- Once logged in user will see a picture with a textbox and a comment 
button
Step 4- User can then enter comments and click on Comment button to publish it 
on their timeline
Step 5- User will be shown Post ID when its successfully shared on facebook
```

Is there anything that I am missing here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a test account Facebook can use. Use the Test Account tool from the App Settings screen to provide an easy login URL.

Give an example URL to a page they can comment on easily. It will speed up the approval process.

The user doesn't need to see the post_id. It has no meaning to them. You should show a confirmation message instead, e.g. "Your comment has been posted successfully".

Is there an easy option for the user to remove their activity from facebook once shared? This is a requirement for any custom action. Is there functionality that lets the user turn-off comment sharing to Facebook? This is also a requirement.

Comment: Well I have already published the comment action using Test Facebook account. However I do not find any link in app settings screen which provides Test Account Tool using which I can provide a login url

Comment: Under `Roles` you can create a new Test User for your application. It also provides a link to login as test user without using username / password. This will make it easier for FB to test.